# Roxy not able to create new project?

Tags: git, github, marklogic, roxy

I'm using my organisation's network. I'm trying to setup a demo roxy project. I used this command -
`ml new my-app --type=hybrid` which resulted into following error.

> Creating new Application: my-app... Cloning into 'my-app'... fatal:
>   unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]:
>   errno=No error github.com[1: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No error
>
> The system cannot find the path specified. The system cannot find the
>   file specified.
>
> You must run this command inside a valid Roxy Project. Use 'ml new' to
>   create a project.
>
> Usage: ml new app-name --server-version=[version] [--branch=branch]
>   [--git] [--force]
>
> use --server-version to specify the major version of MarkLogic you
>   will
>       target in your project (4, 5, 6, 7)   use --branch to specify the GitHub branch of the Roxy project your project
>       will be based on (master, dev)   use --git to automatically configure a git repo   use --force to overwrite an existing directory
>
> done

I'm new to Github. I can see though it's install in my system as when i search git in search bar i see git.exe, git cmd etc.
Need help!

Answer (score 2):

The ml shell or batch script is doing this:

```
git clone git://github.com/${FORK}/roxy.git -b ${BRANCH} ${app_name}.tmp_1
```

Could it be that git protocol is blocked by your companies network?